# Merging multiple columns to one in data frame by sum r

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I want to merge 7 columns in one column by sum, but i can not find a good way to do this. The data frames contains 71 observations and 7 variables.

The first ones are

```
           > head(df)
  pop_exposed_1_1 pop_exposed_1_2 pop_exposed_1_3 pop_exposed_1_4
1              NA              NA        15778358              NA
2              NA              NA              NA              NA
3              NA              NA              NA         3971412
4              NA              NA              NA         2694625
5              NA              NA              NA              NA
6              NA              NA              NA              NA
  pop_exposed_2_2 pop_exposed_2_3 pop_exposed_2_4
1              NA              NA              NA
2        38044072              NA              NA
3              NA              NA              NA
4              NA              NA              NA
5              NA       1626335.0              NA
6              NA        429924.4              NA
```

All the NA values need to be replaced by a value from another variable and some rows have multiple values that need to be combined by sum. So that the outcome is just one variable `pop_exposed`. I have tried several things, but nothing worked the way I would like to.

Comment: This worked fine! I only tried colSums. For another part of my calculation I need to do the same, but combine them by mean instead of sum. Do you maybe know a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up `?rowSums`

```
rowSums(df, na.rm=TRUE)
rowMeans(df, na.rm=TRUE)
```

or  the `apply` way

```
apply(df,1,sum ,na.rm = TRUE)  # Sum  by row '1'  (for columns use '2')
apply(df,1,mean,na.rm = TRUE) # Mean by row '1' (for columns use '2')
```